# ThenInclude Collection are not Including my collection data

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm now currently loading my data using EF Core 2.1 and in my include data has a collection.

I tried `AsEnumerable` and `ToAsyncEmumerable` but it's not working. the breakpoint shows at `balanceQuestion` is `count = 0`

```
public class OutcomeMeasurementTools
{
    [Key] public int OutcomeMeasurementToolsId { get; set; }

    public bool IsWound { get; set; }
    public bool IsPediatrics { get; set; }
    public bool IsPelvic { get; set; }
    public bool IsVestibular { get; set; }
    public bool IsUpperExtremity { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpine { get; set; }
    public bool IsLowerExtremity { get; set; }
    public bool IsBalance { get; set; }
    public bool IsPain { get; set; }
    public bool IsGeneralFunction { get; set; }

    public ProgressNoteObjective ProgressNoteObjective { get; set; }
    public int ProgressNoteObjectiveId { get; set; }

    public Balance Balance { get; set; }

}

public class Balance
{
    [Key] public int BalanceId { get; set; }

    public double? Score { get; set; }

    public bool IsABCScale { get; set; }
    public bool IsBerg { get; set; }
    public bool IsFAB { get; set; } // Fullerton Advanced Balance (FAB) Scale
    public bool IsMSS { get; set; } // Motion Sensitivity Score *
    public bool IsTinetti { get; set; }
    public bool IsMCTSIB { get; set; } // *

    public ICollection<BalanceQuestions> BalanceQuestions { get; set; } // this return count 0 but i have my data in db
    public MSS MSS { get; set; }
    public MCTSIB MCTSIB { get; set; }

    public OutcomeMeasurementTools OutcomeMeasurementTools { get; set; }
    public int OutcomeMeasurementToolsId { get; set; }
}

public class BalanceQuestions
{
    [Key] public int BalanceQuestionId { get; set; }

    public int? Score { get; set; }

    // Identifier
    public bool IsABCScale { get; set; }
    public bool IsBerg { get; set; }
    public bool IsFAB { get; set; } // Fullerton Advanced Balance (FAB) Scale
    public bool IsTinetti { get; set; }

    public int? Q1 { get; set; }
    public int? Q2 { get; set; }
    public int? Q3 { get; set; }
    public int? Q4 { get; set; }
    public int? Q5 { get; set; }
    public int? Q6 { get; set; }
    public int? Q7 { get; set; }
    public int? Q8 { get; set; }
    public int? Q9 { get; set; }
    public int? Q10 { get; set; }
    public int? Q11 { get; set; }
    public int? Q12 { get; set; }
    public int? Q13 { get; set; }
    public int? Q14 { get; set; }
    public int? Q15 { get; set; }


    public Balance Balance { get; set; }
    public int BalanceId { get; set; }
}

public async Task<OutcomeMeasurementTools> GetOutcomeMeasurementTools(int progressNoteObjectiveId)
{
    return await progressNoteRepo.GetOutcomeMeasurementTools(progressNoteObjectiveId)
            .Include(x => x.Balance)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.BalanceQuestions)
            .Include(x => x.Balance)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.MCTSIB)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.C1)
            .Include(x => x.Balance)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.MCTSIB)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.C2)
            .Include(x => x.Balance)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.MCTSIB)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.C3)
            .Include(x => x.Balance)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.MCTSIB)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.C4)
            .Include(x => x.Balance)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.MSS).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

}
```

Comment: `public ICollection<BalanceQuestions> BalanceQuestions` should be `public virtual  ICollection<BalanceQuestions> BalanceQuestions` to allow for lazy loading

Comment: Can you show your relavant `DbContext` part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before, the solution is to `Include` the parent again:

```
.Include(x => x.Balance)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.MCTSIB)
.Include(x => x.Balance)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Balance.C1)
```

Please note that Intelisense would not work for the secondary include!
Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4716

Comment: i mean sir this .Include(x => x.Balance).ThenInclude(x => x.BalanceQuestions) the BalanceQuestions is icollection .. and its return 0 or empty arr. the secondary intelisense was working to me ..